# Cannot find function fill in object - works in console but not as a macro

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

Working with Google Apps Scripts in order to write a macro for use with Google Sheets.

I would like to create an array populated with zeroes to serve as a counter for the number of times a person's name appears in a spreadsheet (so that I can generate an email telling them how many documents they have been assigned). The code executes piecemeal from the console, but once I try to execute the function, I an error,

> TypeError: Cannot find function fill in object ,,,.

```
   function sendEmail(){
     var reviewer = new Array();
     reviewer[0]="Rev1";
     reviewer[1]="Rev2";
     reviewer[2]="Rev3";

     var NewSteward = new Array(reviewer.length).fill(0)
   }
```

Again, if I execute just the the line

```
  var NewSteward = new Array(reviewer.length).fill(0)
```

in the console, I generate the 0-filled array, but for some reason executing the function throws the error.

Comment: What console are you talking about?

Comment: The one that pops up when I hit  Ctrl + Shift + J. Which I realized (after posting this question) is related to Chrome and not Google Apps Script :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Google Apps Script (GAS), `fill()` cannot be used. Because `fill()` was added from ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), and GAS doesn't support ES6 yet. So when you use `fill(0)`, for example, you can use the following modified script.

#### Modified script :

```
function sendEmail(){
  var reviewer = new Array();
  reviewer[0]="Rev1";
  reviewer[1]="Rev2";
  reviewer[2]="Rev3";

//  var NewSteward = new Array(reviewer.length).fill(0)
  var NewSteward = Array.apply(null, Array(reviewer.length)).map(function(){return 0}); // Modified
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!